# concurrent garbage collection for a c++ graph data structure

Tags: c++, memory-management, graph, concurrency, garbage-collection

I have a directed graph data structure used for audio signal processing (see http://audulus.com if you're curious).

I would like graph edges to be strong references, so in the absence of cycles, `std::shared_ptr` would do the trick. Alas, there are potentially cycles in the graph.

So, I had this idea for a simple concurrent mark-sweep collector:

> The mutator thread sends events to the collector thread. The collector thread maintains its own representation of the graph and does not traverse the mutator thread's graph. The collector thread just uses mark-sweep at regular intervals.

The events would be the following (in function call form):

- `AddRoot(Node*)`
- `RemoveRoot(Node*)`
- `AddEdge(Node*, Node*)`
- `RemoveEdge(Node*, Node*)`

Is this scheme correct? The collector thread has an older version of what the mutator thread sees. My intuition is that since a node that is unreachable at an earlier time will still be unreachable at a later time, the collector thread may delete an unreachable object as soon as it finds one.

Also, if it's correct for one mutator thread, would it work for multiple mutator threads?

**UPDATE**

I've released the code here: https://github.com/audulus/collector. The code is actually fairly general purpose. Use `RootPtr<T>` to automatically keep track of  root nodes. Links between nodes are managed using `EdgePtr<T>`.

The collector seems to work for multiple mutator threads (both in my app and in unit tests), but I feel like a proof of correctness is needed.

**PLEASE NOTE** (in repsonse to @AaronGolden's comment below, **judging from the comments below, people aren't reading this**): The mutator thread is responsible for calling the collector functions in the correct order. For example, if the mutator thread calls `RemoveEdge(a,b)` before assigning `b` to a `RootPtr`, the collector may intervene and collect `b`.

**UPDATE 2**:

I've updated the code to my latest version and updated the link above. I've now used the code in my app for over a year and haven't attributed any bugs to it.

Comment: I don't see why `std::shared_ptr` doesn't suffice. When does an edge become obsolete, when do cycles, vertices?

Comment: Hey @stefan, thanks for your reply! The issue is the old cycle problem with reference counting. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Advantages_and_disadvantages

Comment: What about breaking the cycle through resetting an edge? You didn't actually answer my question which is "When does a cycle become obsolete"

Comment: @stefan Given the application domain, I assume that there is some set of "root" nodes - signal sources - and that nodes not reachable from the root nodes are garbage.

Comment: @Casey, right (though they're not signal sources). The root set seen by the collector would be controlled with the `AddRoot` and `RemoveRoot` events.

Comment: If your mutator thread removes an edge making node `n` unreachable and then adds a new edge making `n` reachable again, and your collection thread happens to free `n` between those actions, you're going to have trouble.

I think you'll need to lock your event queue to perform garbage collection, which means you're still going to have the possibility of intermittent reduced responsiveness due to garbage collection.

Comment: @AaronGolden, I'm assuming the mutator thread is careful about the order in which it calls `AddEdge` and `RemoveEdge`. In ObjC parlance, your example is like calling release before retain.

Comment: I assume then it would be too expensive to detect a cycle when an edge is added? If you are willing to do that, you could make an edge that introduces a cycle use a weak reference, to make the strong reference edges cycle free.

Comment: @jxh, that's an interesting idea! I could detect edges which cause cycles by using the topological sort of the graph which I already have. Adding an edge that goes backward in the topsort order causes a cycle. However, I want all edges to retain ownership, because it makes the code a lot cleaner with respect to fading out parts of the signal processing graph when they are deleted by the user, among other edits to the graph.

Comment: Why do you need to specifically inform the collector about the edges? Normally what it needs is just the root set. It can follow edges itself.

Comment: @n.m., good question! The notifications are sent because the collector can be run in a background thread. In a typical "stop-the-world" GC, the collector would just traverse the edges. Though, because its C++ there's no introspection facility to make that easy.

Comment: Graph-traversing GC can be stop-the-world, incremental or fully concurrent. You need to tell GC how to traverse each node type, once per type (not per instance!) and which node has which type (this can be done e.g. with RTTI). No need to notify when an edge is created or destroyed.

Comment: concurrent Mark and Sweep garbage collection is a complicated problem if you want to perform well you don't want to create your own thread but always operate from within another thread. by quickly looking at our favorite open source compiler library i found this: http://llvm.org/docs/GarbageCollection.html

Comment: @n.m. I previously wrote a GC that worked that way (a virtual function, Collectable::gc, which the user would override, was responsible for traversal), but because it traverses the same graph as the mutator, I didn't know how to make it concurrent. Can you explain further how one would overcome that?

Comment: Are you familiar with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Tri-color_marking)?

Comment: @n.m., I suppose, insofar as I understand how tri-color marking works. Why?

Comment: So what is the problem of implementing such a scheme? You have to make the mutator(s) maintain the coloring invariant, and you have to use memory barriers in order to keep access synchronized. I am not aware of any other issue here...

Comment: @n.m. can the invariant be maintained without blocking the mutators? It wasn't apparent to me how to accomplish that. One of my constraints is that the GC has to be lock-free because of my real-time DSP thread. Is there a concurrent collector library for c++ out there? The Boehm collector seems to need to stop threads during collection.

Comment: I would suggest that you find a good description or three of a REAL GC implementation and study it/them.  There are a number of "tricks".  Eg, understanding color marking is important, and it's good to have a color that you can "flip", so that black becomes white for the next cycle, so you don't have to reset everything.

Comment: Concurrency, of course, requires that the "mutator thread" arrive at well-defined "safe points" from time to time, so that deletions can be "committed".  And, to account for objects which may only be addressed by temps (if that's possible), you may need a "write barrier" mechanism for part of each GC cycle.

Comment: @AaronGolden - There are several ways around the remove/add problem.  A "write barrier" is one option.

Comment: @HotLicks, I think you missed my **PLEASE NOTE** above. Also, I don't believe my implementation requires any safe points. I'm studying other implementations with the limited time I have, but if you could look at my approach, rather than simply dismissing it, that would be great :-)

Comment: Yep, your explicit calls in the mutator is a form of the "write barrier".

Answer (score 1):

One argument I think is somewhat persuasive (though I would hesitate to call it proof) that this scheme works is that in the absence of cycles, the scheme is equivalent to reference counting with atomic reference counts.

In the absence of cycles, `AddRoot` and `AddEdge` map to incrementing a reference count and `RemoveRoot` and `RemoveEdge` map to decrementing. Pushing an event onto the queue (I use boost::lockfree::queue) is an atomic operation just like the updating reference counts.

So then the remaining question is: how do cycles change the picture in terms of correctness? To wave hands a bit, cycles are a property of the connectivity of the graph, but don't have an effect on the atomicity of the operations or the ability of one thread to know something earlier than it would otherwise (causing a potential bad ordering of operations).

This would suggest that if there's a counterexample for the scheme, it will involve playing some game with cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting read, and for sharing the code, I'm hopeful my current project will be going in a direction where I need something like this and can dig in more.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this scheme correct?

I'm concerned that you don't have any concept of safe points. In particular, can an update require more than one of your actions to be executed atomically? Perhaps it is ok because you can always add all vertices and edges in a batch before removing.

> Also, if it's correct for one mutator thread, would it work for multiple mutator threads?

If one thread drops a root to a subgraph just after another picks up a root to the same subgraph then you must make sure you get the messages in-order which means you cannot use per-mutator queues. And a global queue is likely to kill scalability.

> One of my constraints is that the GC has to be lock-free because of my real-time DSP thread

1. Is the allocator lock-free?
2. What if the GC cannot keep up with mutator(s)?

Also, I would recommend considering:

1. Forking and collecting in a child process.
2. Incremental mark-sweep with Dijkstra's tricolor marking sceme.
3. Baker's treadmill.
4. VCGC.
5. Separate per-thread heaps with deep copying of messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't believe any of the updates require multiple actions to be executed atomically. I think this scheme doesn't need safe points because the mutator is notifying the collector, rather than the collector pausing things briefly to determine roots. I'm not sure I understand safe points though.

Comment: Right, I need a single global queue, which is somewhat unfortunate. In my app though, I only have two threads involved, so its not that bad.

Comment: The allocator (malloc) isn't lock free, but I'm careful to only allocate in the non-realtime thread and then pass the object to the DSP thread. If the GC can't keep up, then the queue has to allocate more space, which is a problem -- I just use a sufficiently large queue so that's unlikely.